# Storing linked lists on cloud (when network connection is intermittent)

Tags: database-design, data-structures, linked-list, cloud-storage

I have a data structure which looks like this-

```
------
|List| => Entity1 -> Entity2 -> Entity3 -> Entity4 -> NULL
------
```

The idea is to let a user create a `List` with an ordered set of `Entity`s on the mobile and save it on a server.

The operations a user can do with the `List` and the `Entity`s are

- Add an entity
- Delete an entity
- Delete a list (which would mean traversing the whole list and deleting an entity)
- Insert an entity
- Move an entity

On there server, there can be hundreds of such lists.

Question is how should such linked lists be stored on the cloud. Should I do it the way it is done locally, that is

1. Create a head of the list on the server
2. Get response with a pointer to the head of the list
3. Create an entity on the server
4. Add a pointer to this entity to the head of the list as the starting entity

The problem is every time a new list is created, it introduces some synchronization problems. Basically, say if steps 1-3 are done and then the mobile connection gets lost, then the entity is lost and it can not be retrived from the linked list.

Is there a better way to do this to prevent such losses when a process can not be completed in one go?

Comment: If your looking for an example of how to do it, have a look at the source of Apache Kafka.  Their solution is much much more complex than what your looking for, but it may give you some ideas. 

Also, Amazon's SQS would pretty much already solve the problem for you.  And save you a lot of time.